# How to solve the Problem with my Dashboard?

Tags: shiny, plotly, flexdashboard, ggplotly

I'm using R Markdown for Flexdashboard. My problem is with filtering data in dashboard. When I'm adding renderPlotly function my chart is appearing in Flexdashboard but not every time that I've running the document and also it doesn't appear in web browser. Could you help me to find this problem.

```
title: "XXX"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    logo: logo.png
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    social: [ "menu", "twitter", "facebook", "linkedin"]
    runtime: shiny
     theme:
      version: 4
      bg: "#FBEFF2" #dashboard color
      fg: "#666666"  # text color
      primary: "#F16C8B"  # navig bar color
      headings-color: "#666666" 
      base_font: 
        google: Fraunces
      heading_font:
        google: Fraunces


year <- as.numeric(sort(unique(users$Year)))
selectInput("Year", 
        label = "Select Year", 
        choices = c("All", year), selected = "All")
```

```
filtered_users_a_grouped <- reactive({if(input$Year!= "All"){filter(users_a_grouped, Year %in% input$Year)} else {users_a_grouped}})

renderPlotly({ggplotly(filtered_users_a_grouped() %>% count(Age_range, `Marital Status`) %>% arrange(Age_range, `Marital Status`) %>% group_by(Age_range, `Marital Status`) %>% mutate(n = sum(n)) %>%    
ggplot(aes(x = Age_range, y = n,  fill = `Marital Status`)) + geom_col(width=0.8) + labs(title = "", y = "", x = "")})
```

Comment: The script included for `renderPlotly` has a syntax problem ) missing

Comment: Thank you, I've shortened my code and forgot ggplotly )
But believe me there is another problem